# React Native add Screens dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to add screens dynamically from a changeable array.

This works:
[image]

but this doesn't work:
[image]
It says: Error: Couldn't find any screens for the navigator. Have you defined any screens as its children?

How can I fix the second to be more "dynamic"?

Comment: can u `console.log(element)`? I think element is a component, you cant change to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your `components` to list of objects.

then loop inside the item by their key and value.

```
const components = [
 {
   name: "Home",
   element: HomeScreen
 },
 {
   name: "Details",
   element: DetailsScreen
 }
];

const renderScreen = () => {
  let result = null;

  if (components) {
    result = components.map((item, i) => {
       return <Stack.Screen name={item.name} element={item.element} />
    });
  }

  return result;
}

return(
  {renderScreen()}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

change `element => { <Stack... /> }` to `element => { return <Stack... /> }` or  `element => ( <Stack... /> )`